# Whatsapp cloud API not delivering media messages to iOS / iphone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, facebook-debugger

I am working with whatsapp cloud api to send messages to clients, it is working fine with android but not working with IOS, are there any additional steps of setup for IOS ?

Normal messages with only text are delivered properly, but messages with images or documents are not being delivered.

The API is returning code 200 for messages sent to Android and iOS but only Android users are receiving the message delivered.

Example code:

```
   url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{}/messages'.format(FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID)
   headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(ACCESS_TOKEN),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
   data = {
   "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
   "recipient_type": "individual",
   "to": "{}".format(numero),
   "type": "template",
   "template":{
            "name":"bancario_atm",
            "language":{
               "code":"en_US"
            },
            "components":[
               {
                  "type":"header",
                  "parameters":[{
                     "type":"document",
                     "document":{
                        "id":"{}".format(media_id),
                        "filename":"Reporte_{}_{}_{}.xlsx".format(entidad,fecha_proceso, fecha_hora)
                     },
                  }]
               },
               {
                  "type":"body",
                  "parameters":[
                     {
                        "type":"text",
                        "text":"%s" % fecha_proceso
                     },
                     {
                        "type":"text",
                        "text":"%s" % fecha_hora
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }

   response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

The [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/troubleshooting) says that the Whatsapp app version has to be superior to 2.21.170.4, I checked with the test phone app version I'm using and that's OK, so that is not the problem.

Sometimes the media message appears but only on Whatsapp Web, not on the Phone, that makes me think there's some config Whatsapp is not communicating clear.